# How to read dimension values from custom attribute?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-attributes

I have custom Button which is completely made up by my own xml. I can set up style, color and text + icon to it, but now I need to set custom text size.

I added to my styleable attributes new attribute `<attr name="l_buttonTextSize" format="dimension"/>` then I set value for textSize from dimensions `app:l_buttonTextSize="@dimen/text_small"`. But I cant read it in button initialization.

This is how I read that value:

```
val buttonTxtSize = typedArray.getFloat(btnTextSizeIndex, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.text_medium))
setButtonTextSize(buttonTxtSize)

fun setButtonTextSize(value: Float){
    buttonText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, value)
}
```

I've got this exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12.0sp"
```

Looks like string was send instead of dimension value as float.

Comment: `getDimension` instead `getFloat`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getDimensionPixelSize`

```
val buttonTxtSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(btnTextSizeIndex, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.text_medium))
```